# C# - Как сделать появление объекта в рандомное время ? Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d, таймер, случайные-числа

Я делаю 2D игру в Unity. В ней есть три курицы, которые должны в течении 1-10 секунд создавать в определённом месте яйца, а также при появлении яиц у куриц должна срабатывать анимация. Яйца не должны создаваться в одно и тоже время. Даже нет предположений как это реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. делаешь класс который генерит яйца
2. у класса должен быть список под гейм обжекты - туда перетягиваешь всех своих куриц
3. При помощи короутины https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html ждешь случайное количество секунд (это можно реализовать при помощи `Random.Range(1,10)`)
4. Рандомом выбираешь случайную курицу из списка и гереришь яйцо именно внутри этой короутины из этой курицы

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122664/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-c-------).